# INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` in multiple websites

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, mysql, indexer

one question to the community:

## Questions

why does magento reindex each website ?
in our situation all website have the same store

Why does Magento only reindex 500 entitys ?

## SQL Statement

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) 

SELECT `cc`.`entity_id` AS `category_id`, `ccp`.`product_id`, ccp.position +
10000 AS `position`, 0 AS `is_parent`, 3 AS `store_id`, IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) AS `visibility` 
FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `cc`

INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity` AS `cc2` ON cc2.path LIKE CONCAT(`cc`.`path`, '/%') AND cc.entity_id NOT IN (1)\n 
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.category_id = cc2.entity_id\n 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `cpw` ON cpw.product_id = ccp.product_id\n 
INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpsd` ON cpsd.entity_id = ccp.product_id AND cpsd.store_id = 0 AND cpsd.attribute_id = 96\n 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpss` ON cpss.entity_id = ccp.product_id AND cpss.attribute_id = cpsd.attribute_id AND cpss.store_id = 3\n 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvd` ON cpvd.entity_id = ccp.product_id AND cpvd.store_id = 0 AND cpvd.attribute_id = 102\n 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvs` ON cpvs.entity_id = ccp.product_id AND cpvs.attribute_id = cpvd.attribute_id AND cpvs.store_id = 3\n 
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `ccad` ON ccad.entity_id = cc.entity_id AND ccad.store_id = 0 AND ccad.attribute_id = 51\n 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `ccas` ON ccas.entity_id = cc.entity_id AND ccas.attribute_id = ccad.attribute_id AND ccas.store_id = 3 WHERE (cpw.website_id = '3') AND (IFNU
LL(cpss.value, cpsd.value) = 1) AND (IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) IN (4, 2)) AND (IFNULL(ccas.value, ccad.value) = 1) AND (`cc`.`entity_id` >= 18
501) AND (`cc`.`entity_id` < 19001)
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento reindexes all your websites because it doesn't know they are the same, it doesn't even check if they are the same, because checking this would take more than reindexing.

As for the second part...magento does not reindex only 500 entities.
It reindexes 500 entities at  once.
See this line in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::rebuild()`

```
$categoriesIdsChunks = array_chunk($categoriesIds[$store->getRootCategoryId()], 500);
```

That splits the categories into chunks of 500. That is followed by a `foreach` loop that indexes each chunk.

```
        foreach ($categoriesIdsChunks as $categoriesIdsChunk) {
            $attributesData = $this->_getAttributeValues($categoriesIdsChunk, $store->getId());
            $data = array();
            foreach ($categories[$store->getRootCategoryId()] as $category) {
                if (!isset($attributesData[$category['entity_id']])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $category['store_id'] = $store->getId();
                $data[] = $this->_prepareValuesToInsert(
                    array_merge($category, $attributesData[$category['entity_id']])
                );
            }
            $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertMultiple($this->getMainStoreTable($store->getId()), $data);
        }
```